# Can anybody help why there is so much empty space in my vs code terminal?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

[image]

Can anybody explain How I can solve this too much empty space problem in the Visual Studio Code terminal?

Comment: Please [don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). Copy-paste text *as text* into your questions, both code and errors and output/input.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And then learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Answer (score 0):

The `c` script seems to output multiple empty lines before trying to compile your source file.

Comment: ig u r right,anyway to solve it?